# How to install Thwab in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, package-management

I want to read my .bok file from maktaba shamela in Ubuntu 12.04. I tried install it by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sabily.team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

And then I installed it. But then showed:

```
E: unable locate thwab package.
```

And I tried other way, dowloading `thwab-lib_1.1.2.orig.tar.gz`.

But I don't know how to install `thwab-lib_1.1.2.orig.tar.gz` in Ubuntu. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

After the 2 commands I went to USC and it *is* there (mind you: I SEARCHED for thwab and it shows thawab!!):

[image]

So you probably need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install thawab
```

No thwab in the USC ....

Looking at the contents of the PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~sabily.team/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75](https://launchpad.net/%7Esabily.team/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75)

Found a DEB Installer for thwab here: [https://launchpad.net/~sabily.team/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/1415835/+listing-archive-extra](https://launchpad.net/%7Esabily.team/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/1415835/+listing-archive-extra)

So download that and install the DEB by clicking it and have USC handle it.

Comment: Is this related to what version is being run? Does the PPA provide a package for 12.04? Also, does spelling have to do with it. Your USC screenshot shows it as `thawab` but the questions says `thwab`.

Comment: @Eliah kagan: both are same package, It is just a packaging issue :)

Comment: seems like a packaging issue indeed. Or Thawab is the new Twab.